# Timeout using SSTableloader for Cassandra Aws Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I'm trying to use sstableloader to load SSTable (.db) files into a Cassandra Cluster running on an AWS EC2 instance.  This error occurrs:

```
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Streaming relevant part of C:\Users\SNCUser\dataquest\CassandraLoader\WrDir\beed5b97-0b52-45d7-be5d-fbbac00ac607\device_data\blob\device_data-blob-ka-1-Data.db to [/172.*.*.*]


ERROR 16:08:36 [Stream #1114a0d0-1054-11e5-9ccc-65ee5fdd8902] Streaming error occurred
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:458) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:450) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadConnectionFactory.createConnection(BulkLoadConnectionFactory.java:62) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.createConnection(StreamSession.java:233) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler.initiate(ConnectionHandler.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.start(StreamSession.java:220) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator$StreamSessionConnector.run(StreamCoordinator.java:208) [apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]

progress: total: 100% 0  MB/s(avg: 0 MB/s)WARN  16:08:36 [Stream #1114a0d0-1054-11e5-9ccc-65ee5fdd8902] Stream failed
```

I use "sstableloader -d publicip path\keyspace\table", which works for localhost, but not for the public ip address of the EC2 instance (I blurred out the actual ip for the address 172.*.*.*).

Might have to do with the EC2 firewall, however the settings for port 80 are open on the instance (tcping times out though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to open the server ports in your security group. Port 80 is not used for inter node communication. The full list is here:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureFireWall_r.html